# How to block media ads and search ads?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am interested in rolling out my own Ad Blocker extension and I have been successful in blocking quite a lot of ads (from AdSense, etc.) using Chrome extension's [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API.

Basically I prematurely cancel web requests being made to hosts I found from [this repository](https://github.com/StevenBlack/hosts/blob/master/hosts).

However, I am still trying to figure out ways to block **media ads** (from Youtube, Soundcloud, etc.) and **search ads** (from Google, Bing, etc.)

I believe that I can pinpoint the `<div>`, `<ul>` or `<ol>` elements containing ads by manually inspecting the search engines' search result pages and set their `display` style to `none`, but am still looking for smarter ways of doing it.

With regards to the **media ads** I am pretty much clueless at the moment.

Any tips are welcomed.

Comment: AFAIK there's no magic method and can't be one. If you inspect other efficient blockers you'll see how complicated their heuristics are.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for sharing your knowledge. I can definitely target specific html elements by their `class` tags. (assuming those are not susceptible to frequent changes) The problem is the media ads like those "pre-roll" and "in-between' ads in Youtube. Any ideas would be appreciated.